# Are elements of $\mathbb{Q}$ unique by value?

Tags: field-theory, rational-numbers

I usually visualize elements $\frac{a}{b} \in\mathbb{Q}$ as $(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}\times(\mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\})$. By this construction, I think it's pretty clear that elements of $\mathbb{Q}$ may have the same value but have a different representation (i.e. $\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{4}$) and therefore I consider different ordered pairs unique when I think of elements, despite having the same value. However, I find that when I think of $\mathbb{Q}$ as a whole, I tend to think of congruence classes and $\frac{1}{2}=\frac{2}{4}$.

I still think the former is more accurate, but in a general case **does it really matter** (if we're not specifically looking for relationships between numerators and denominators and some other factors)?

Comment: What exactly is the question here?  Yes, $1/2$ and $2/4$ are the same rational number.  How you think of them doesn't matter, as long as you don't lose sight of that fact.

Comment: The question is implicit in your use of the word "them" rather than "it" above. The OP thinks of 1/2 and 2/4 as them in some cases and it in others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The set of rational numbers is not the same as $\mathbb{Z}\times(\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\})$, but rather
$$ \mathbb{Q}=(\mathbb{Z}\times(\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}))/\sim$$
where we say that $(a,b)\sim(c,d)$ if $ad=bc$.

Therefore there are infinitely many pairs $(a,b)$ corresponding to a given rational number. However, we can choose a canonical representative of each equivalence class by requiring that $b>0$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking

Answer (score 1):

There is no significant difference between the two versions. You can think of $\frac{a}{b}$ as a funny way of writing $(a,b)$, stacked vertically and with a vinculum as separator, instead of stacked horizontally with a comma as separator, and with two outside parentheses. Each denotes an ordered pair.

The "value" of $(a,b)$, or of its stacked version, is the equivalence class it determines.

Comment: That's a most unusual point of view. I think most people view  $(a, b)$ as a notation for a pairing operation satisfying $(a, b) = (x,y)$ iff $a = x$ and $b = y$, and view $\frac{a}{b}$ as a notation for a quotient operation, defined only for $b \neq 0$ and satisfying $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{x}{y}$ iff $ay = bx$. The vinculum in $\frac{a}{b}$ means "divided by" not "juxtaposed with".

Comment: @RobArthan: True, though when one formalizes division in set theory, the differences are not very great.

Comment: When you formalise $\frac{a}{b}$ in set theory (as a member of a formalisation of the rational numbers as a field), then your formalisation is broken if it distinguishes $\frac{2}{3}$ from $\frac{4}{6}$, while a formalisation of pairs is broken if it identifies $(2, 3)$ with $(4, 6)$. So that's quite a considerable difference between fractions and pairs.

Comment: @RobArthan: That was informally taken care of in my answer by assigning to each  a "value" (equivalence class).

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't conform with normal mathematical usage, either informal or formal: informally $(a, b)$ and $\frac{a}{b}$ are both identified with their denotations ("values"); formally, $(a, b)$ and  $\frac{a}{b}$ are syntactic short-hands for the application of two distinct two-argument function symbols to the terms $a$ and $b$, say $\mathsf{pair}(a, b)$ and $\mathsf{quotient}(a, b)$. In both the formal and informal view the differences are significant.

Comment: At the informal level, the usual manipulations of fractions are done in the way that gets "imitated" by the operations on (equivalence classes of) ordered pairs when we define the rationals from the integers.

Comment: I think $(2, 5) = 4/10$ would be viewed as a category error rather than a truth by most people.

Comment: @RobArthan:  Probably by me also, but at the manipulational level operations with $(4,10)$ and $\frac{4}{10}$ are remarkably similar.

Comment: OK - shall we agree to differ on this one.

Comment: @RobArthan: Yes, and with you having the better of it. My argument is that at the level of symbol manipulation, differences become much less clear.

Answer (score 1):

The map is not the territory.

The way you present an element is not the same way as the element itself. The fact that $\frac12$ and $\frac24$ are equal does not mean that $\frac12$ and $\frac24$ are different. These are just *two* ways of presenting the same number. Just as $1+2$ and $4-1$ are the same way writing $3$.

The point is that we have a canonical way of writing every rational number: $q$ can be written uniquely as $\frac rs$ where $r\in\Bbb Z$ and $s\in\Bbb N\setminus\{0\}$ are coprime. Now observe that $\frac24$ does not have this presentation, where $\frac12$ does.

Answer (score 0):

I take this to be a philosophical question. If we have two different formalisms for a thing, which one is "really" that thing? Or are different formalisms interchangeable, as long as the things they designate have the same *behavior*?

Set theory is full of problems like this. The natural number $3$ is not the same set as the integer $3$ which is not the same set as the real number $3$. There are "canonical injections" that allow mathematicians to ignore these set-theoretical anomalies. Yet in set theory it's axiomatic (literally!) that two sets are the same if and only if they have the same elements. It's standard in math to regard this issue as unimportant and never mention it. That is as it should be, because this is a *philosophical* problem and not a mathematical one.

The philosopher Paul Benecerraf wrote a famous essay called [What Numbers Could Not Be](http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic1240846.files/Benacerraf.pdf) that discusses this problem.

You can formalize the idea that "two things are the same thing if they have the same behaviors" through [Category theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory); and I have heard that this issue relates to the philosophical doctrine of [mathematical structuralism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structuralism_(philosophy_of_mathematics)).

Barry Mazur wrote an essay on this topic, titled [When is one thing equal to some other thing](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~mazur/preprints/when_is_one.pdf)? It's a far more worthwhile read than anything I could say on this topic.

Comment: The link to Paul Benacerraf's paper at `isites.harvard.edu` is broken. However, a snapshot is saved on the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20150907142512/http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic1240846.files/Benacerraf.pdf). The paper can also be found at [doi:10.2307/2183530](https://doi.org/10.2307/2183530).